# Converting String Date to Date Time in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, date, datetime

I have a situation where I need to convert the datetime value stored as string to Timestamp:

*I am using oracle database*

This actually works for me `select TO_DATE('11-27-2013 21:28:41', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;`

But my date value now is diffent from the above:
`select TO_DATE('Sunday 6/1/2014 8:00AM', 'MM-DD-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') from dual;` - failed. I have 'Sunday' inside my date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify a correct format mask to the `TO_DATE` function. See a full list of format masks along with documentation for the function here: http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/to_date.php

You can correct your problem by:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('Sunday 6/1/2014 8:00AM', 'DAY M/D/YYYY HH:MIAM') FROM DUAL;
```

Comment: how to handle this??
select to_date('Mon Apr 14 00:00:00 EDT 2014','Day Mon DD HH:MI:SS YYYY') from dual;

Comment: @user3899117: My bad. Apologies. Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the correct format.  I think this will work:

```
select TO_DATE('Sunday 6/1/2014 8:00AM', 'DAY MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI AM')
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/33525) is a SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The following seems to work fine:

```
SELECT TO_DATE('Sunday 6/1/2014 8:00AM', 'DAY MM/DD/YYYY HH:MIAM') FROM DUAL
```

Share and enjoy.

Comment: That worked for me..thanks!!

how to convert this?? 'Mon Apr 14 00:00:00 EDT 2014'

Comment: select to_date('Mon Apr 14 00:00:00 EDT 2014','Day Mon DD HH:MI:SS YYYY') from dual;